# How to properly index a table two other tables have a one-to-many relationship to?

Tags: sql, indexing, database, one-to-many

Imagine I have three tables, called "customers", "companies" and "phone_numbers". Both customers and companies can have multiple phone numbers. What would be the best way to index phone_numbers? Have both customer_id and company_id and keep one of them null? What if there are more than two tables with a one-to-many relationship with phone_numbers?

Comment: Which database server are you using ? MySQL ? MS SQL Server ? Other ? And what kind of query will you use ? Will you generally try to get the phone numbers for one company/customer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your business rules might only state one-to-many, but in reality people & companies can be a many-to-many relationship.  One person can have many phone numbers (home, cell, etc), and a phone number can relate to many people (myself, my significant other, etc).  Likewise, a company number and my business number can be the same - you just use an extension number to reach me directly.

Indexing the foreign keys would be a good idea, but beware of premature optimization.  Depending on setup, I'd consider a unique constraint on the phone number column but I would not have the phone number column itself as a primary key.

Comment: In the many to many case couldn't you just check to see if the number already exists then if it does, return back the key value of the phone number that already exists? 

for instance Customer A has Number a Company X has the same number a, so return a's id. Where as normal behavior if Company X's number was different would be to create a new record then return that id.

Comment: @msarchet: Properly setup constraints will do the same, while only needing to perform one query.  Just need to gracefully handle the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with identity columns in the customer and company tables, then in the phone number table do as you said and keep one null and the other populated. I do something similar to this and it works out fine as long as you validate data so that it doesn't go in with both values being null. For a more elegant solution you could have two columns: one that is an id, and another that is a type identifier. Say 1 for customers and 2 for companies, that way you don't have to worry about null data or a lot of extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add two columns to the phone_numbers table.  The first would be an index that tells you what table to associate with (say, 1 = customers and 2 = companies).  The second would be the foreign key to the appropriate table.

This way you can add as many phone number sources as you want.

If a particular person or company has more than one phone number, there would be multiple rows in the phone_numbers table.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have to a pattern is the following -- any two entities with a many-to-many relationship require an associative entity (a cross-reference table) between them, like so (surrogate keys assumed):

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_XREF_PHONE
( CUSTOMER_ID      NUMBER NOT NULL,
  PHONE_NUMBER_ID  NUMBER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT       CUSTOMER_XREF_PHONE_PK 
    PRIMARY KEY      (CUSTOMER_ID, PHONE_NUMBER_ID),
  CONSTRAINT       CUSTOMER_XREF_PHONE_UK 
    UNIQUE           (PHONE_NUMBER_ID, CUSTOMER_ID),
  CONSTRAINT       CUSTOMER_XREF_PHONE_FK01
    FOREIGN KEY      (CUSTOMER_ID)
      REFERENCES       CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT       CUSTOMER_XREF_PHONE_FK02
    FOREIGN_KEY      (PHONE_NUMBER_ID)
      REFERENCES       PHONE_NUMBERS (PHONE_NUMBER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Such an implementation pattern can:

- Be fully protected by database-level referential integrity constraints
- Support bi-directional access (sometimes you need to see who else has that phone number)
- Be self-cleaning if your database supports `ON DELETE CASCADE`
- Be extended through the use of a "relationship type" attribute to map multiple independent relationships between the entities,
  such as:

  - customer has a home telephone number
  - customer has a daytime telephone number
  - customer has a fax telephone number
  - customer has a mobile telephone number